# Cutting down on power by bypassing mechanical to electrical conversions: Why not?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, electricity, efficient-energy-use

The only answer to this I can think of is energy portability issues.

Another modern-world insanity is converting mechanical energy to electrical, only to turn it back into mechanical. The example I like to use is a refrigerator's reciprocating compressor.

If we directly attach a steam turbine's axle to the crankshaft of the compressor, we will not need to suffer losses in heat in our conversion of mechanical to electrical (at the power plant) then back to mechanical energy (in our appliance).

Comment: **You can't transfer mechanical energy directly over long distances.**  That's why electrical systems like the power grid exist: to transport a standard, universal form of energy over a standard medium to anywhere we want, and then convert that energy to any other form we want locally.

Comment: And many small engines are less efficient than one big engine at the power company.

Comment: @JonCuster You talk about efficiency. Is it more efficient to transport energy and lose much of it on the way as heat, or to directly setup a small (less-efficient) engine at home and run the fridge? I'm not challenging you, but simply asking.

Comment: @ElFlea - you need to understand the high efficiency of transmitting electrical power over long distances. It isn’t nearly as bad as you seem to believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long ago, a primitive factory used one big engine or turbine or water wheel to rotate a set of overhead shafts, from which leather belts were suspended at intervals to power small pieces of machinery scattered throughout the factory. This arrangement was inflexible in that when the single big engine stopped, so did the entire factory, and when electricity came into common use, this *overhead shafting* arrangement fell quickly out of favor.

The power losses in long-distance electrical power transmission are more than made up for by the ease with which it is performed and the flexibility it affords. This makes "local power generation" as you describe it impractical because a hundred small steam turbines are much more wasteful of heat energy than one large turbine.

The only practical exception is *integrated co-generation* in which a small engine running on, for example, natural gas powers a generator while also spinning the shaft of a heat pump. The waste heat from the engine's cooling system makes residential hot water, the waste heat from its exhaust goes through a heat exchanger to provide hot air for space heating, the heat pump furnishes air conditioning (or pulls heat from outside the dwelling)  and the electricity from the generator powers up your small appliances in the home while also charging a set of batteries.

Overall thermodynamic efficiency of such a device can exceed 95%, and examples of this technology are just now coming onto the market.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue the ability to transfer between mechanical and electrical energy is the most essential technological revolution which gave us the modern world and not at all an "insanity".

Mechanical energy is great because it does *stuff*. Whether that be turn turbines, power your blender, or heat up your house. Mechanical energy is generally how we take energy from the world (excluding solar panels and nuclear reactors), and how we use it.

There's a few problems however, you can't transmit mechanical energy, you cannot efficiently store mechanical energy, you cannot turn on and off sources of mechanical energy, there is tremendous detail and lack of portability in each type of mechanical energy (you can't just hook up your car engine to a toaster).

Enter electricity!

For the most part electrical energy is able to solve all of those issues for us. We are able to source our energy production to large scale suppliers that distribute it easily with transmission lines; they manage all of the difficulties of generators. We can easily turn on and off appliances with little loss on the source side. We can use the same voltage rating to power up a whole host of devices with different Wattage, as a result we can manage motor torque/speed characteristic. This is not even addressing the genius of 3-Phase power, and induction motor; which are probably more responsible for the modern age than any other invention (in my opinion). Electrical energy also allows us to use a bunch of different types of mechanical energy together to power the grid from coal, natural gas, hydro, nuclear, wind turbines... How would we use any of those on a large scale without the distributive capabilities of electric transmission lines and transformers? And if you don't like large scale (as I can tell from your comments), would we just have nuclear reactors that use pulleys and gears to connect to your hair dryer? Or maybe wind turbine with a mechanical network that connects it to your oven? I think you can begin see the absurdities that would come about in the system you are proposing.

I see from your comments that you may be alluding towards Solar, which is a little different, because the energy is never actually mechanical, it comes from the sun (Electro-Magnetic Energy), which forces a drift current in a solar cell (Electric Energy). I'm all for people having solar cells on their house! But that itself is more electrical energy than the grid!